# How can I split up a string field sentence into words and insert them into a new table with the same key id?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Pads with a field called keywords, it has a list of words aka a sentence.

e.g.

```
Pad
ID=1 Keywords=red brown green
ID=2 keywords=green orange blue
```

The keywords field could have 40 words in it.

I want to create a new table keywords

e.g.

```
Keywords
ID=1 word=red
ID=1 word=brown
ID=1 word=green
ID=2 word=green
ID=2 word=orange
ID=2 word=blue
```

Can someone point me at some sql to create / insert data into this new table?

EDIT - Reply to Spinny Norman, I've got slightly different fields and spaces not commas, however thats all I replaced and I'm getting an error and I can't see why ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot of ways here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html, but they all require you to name the index of the item as well. So, if you know that there is a max number of keywords per item, you could use one of these. An example, for 3 keywords per item:

```
insert into keywords (id, word) (
    select id, replace(substring(substring_index(Keywords, ',', 1), length(substring_index(Keywords, ',', 1 - 1)) + 1), ',', '') as item1
    from Pads
union all
    select id, replace(substring(substring_index(Keywords, ',', 2), length(substring_index(Keywords, ',', 2 - 1)) + 1), ',', '') as item2
    from Pads
union all
    select id, replace(substring(substring_index(Keywords, ',', 3), length(substring_index(Keywords, ',', 3 - 1)) + 1), ',', '') as item3
    from Pads
);
```

You could also filter out null values to be able to use "up to 3 (in this case) keywords".

EDIT: if you're doing this just once, you don't have to use the unions (and also, you should apparently surround the whole union with a select if you do). So, use this instead:

```
insert into words (padid, word)
  select padid, replace(substring(substring_index(English45, ' ', 1), 
   length(substring_index(English45, ' ', 1 - 1)) + 1), ' ', '') as item1
   from Pads
   having item1 <> '';
```

And repeat for 2, 3 etc until no inserts are made any more.

Comment: Well, do you have to do this on a regular basis, or just once? If it's only once, you could just do the insert into...select queries manually until no more rows are inserted.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can't do unions in insert into... select. However, you can now just use 1 select at a time, without the unions. I'll edit.