# how to sort a word within a sting sorted alphabetic order using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have an SQL table that have these kind of strings "Sapa to Hanoi".

i want to change it to "Hanoi to Sapa" because "Hanoi" should come first when sorting alphabet order.

how can i do it in SQL?

Comment: Sorting it is just one application of a list of words, and probably the easiest part. The tricky part is to break up a string into something that allows you to do operations like sorting.

Comment: Please show a wider set of sample input data, along with the expected output.

Comment: For example, have a look at [How can I split up a string field sentence into words and insert them into a new table with the same key id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538259/how-can-i-split-up-a-string-field-sentence-into-words-and-insert-them-into-a-new). Their job was to insert it instead of sort it, but the hard part is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to lexicographically compare the two city names, and then swap positions should the second name belong the first one.

```
SELECT
    field,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' to ', 1) < SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' to ', -1)
         THEN FIELD
         ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' to ', -1), ' to ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' to ', 1)) END AS new_field
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just have two parts, you can reconstruct the string:

```
select concat(least( substring_index(col, ' to ', 1), substring_index(col, ' to ', -1),
              ' to ',
              greatest( substring_index(col, ' to ', 1), substring_index(col, ' to ', -1)
             )
```

However, I would advocate that you put the two city names in *separate* columns.  Then construct the string when you retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

For 3 words? 
Compare the first word with the last and stitch them differently if the order is wrong.

Example:

```
SELECT col, 
CASE 
WHEN (LENGTH(TRIM(col)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(col), ' ', ''))+1) = 3 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(col),' ',1) > SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(col),' ',-1)
THEN CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(col),' ',-1), ' ', 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(col),' ',2),' ',-1), 
   ' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(col),' ',1)) 
ELSE col 
END as sorted
FROM
(
    select 'Foo to Bar' as col 
    union all select 'Bar to Foo' 
    union all select 'Foo'
) q
```

Test [here](http://rextester.com/AFGW69991)

Answer (score 0):

It's another way to produce [***such a query***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06d01c/46) :

```
select group_concat(distinct str_ separator ' ') as str
  from
(  
 select str_ from ( 
   select 
          q.n, 
          substring_index(substring_index(str, ' ', n), ' ', -1 ) as str_
     from tab
    inner join ( select ordinal_position as n
                   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
                  where table_name='COLUMNS' ) q
       on char_length(str) >= n - 1
  ) q1
  order by str_  
) q2;

str
-------------
Hanoi Sapa to
```

for a string composed of three words.